# What C++0x Headers are supposed to define nullptr?

Tags: c++, header, c++11, nullptr

Now that C++0x is almost here, I've been experimenting with it, and in particular using nullptr. I haven't been able to figure out what standard header files one is supposed to include if one needs to use it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: nullptr is only supported by GCC 4.6 or later, or MSVC 10. Maybe your compiler isn't recent enough.

Comment: Centos is known to have older versions of gcc and so thanks for the heads up. (FYI gcc versions for centos: 5 ships 4.1.x, 6 ships 4.4.x, 7 ships 4.8.x.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No headers should be required. It is a built-in keyword (§[lex.nullptr]).

> #### 2.14.7 Pointer literals                 [lex.nullptr]
>
> > *pointer-literal:*
> >             `nullptr`
>
> The pointer literal is the keyword
>   `nullptr`. It is a prvalue of type
>   `std::nullptr_t`. [ *Note:* `std::nullptr_t`
>   is a distinct type that is neither a
>   pointer type nor a pointer to member
>   type; rather, a prvalue of this type
>   is a null pointer constant and can be
>   converted to a null pointer value or
>   null member pointer value. See 4.10
>   and 4.11. *—endnote*]

---

Its type, `std::nullptr_t`, however, is "defined" in the header `<cstddef>` (§[support.types]/9).

> `nullptr_t` is defined as follows:
>
> ```
> namespace std {
>     typedef decltype(nullptr) nullptr_t;
> }
> ```
>
> The type for which `nullptr_t` is a synonym has the characteristics described in 3.9.1 and 4.10. [*Note*: Although `nullptr`’s address cannot be taken, the address of another `nullptr_t` object that is an lvalue can be taken. *—endnote*]

Comment: Thanks! I had originally thought so, but discovered that g++ had stopped accepting nullptr in one of my unit tests. I thought it was a header issue, but somehow my version of g++ had been degraded from 4.6 (which supports it) to 4.5 (which doesn't).

Comment: heh, I love the backwards logic of defining the type of `nullptr` to be "the type of `nullptr`.